# infinite do until loop within for loop in web app

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, for-loop, do-loops

So my code is going through the various components and creates bundles using the `BuildKnittingRecords` sub for the various components. My code works well when it creates the bundles for the `Case "Sleeve", "Front", "Body", "Back"` but when it gets to  `Case "Collar22-32"` it gets stuck in the `do until` loop and as a result will keep on adding to `PnlsToProduce`(until it crashes cos the number is too big) instead of only running through the `do until` loop when it finds that component

```
Private Sub knittingdetailsheaderdataset()
    bundlenum = 1
    Dim SQL As String
    Dim Adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using con As New OleDbConnection(cnString)
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand()
        SQL = "Select bla bla
               FROM bla bla
               INNER Join bla bla" 
        (it's a very long sql statement, and not relevent to my issue)
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = SQL
        Adapter.SelectCommand = cmd
        Adapter.Fill(dt)
        For dr As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
                componentName = dt(dr)(6)
                knittOrderID = dt(dr)(4)
                componentID = dt(dr)(3)
                sizeID = dt(dr)(5)
                qtyppnl = dt(dr)(10)
                Select Case componentName
                    Case "Sleeve", "Front", "Body", "Back"
                        MxBndleSz = 36
                        PnlsToProduce = dt(dr)(11)
                        BuildKnittingRecords(MxBndleSz, componentID, sizeID, PnlsToProduce, qtyppnl, knittOrderID, bundlenum)                       
                    Case "Collar22-32"
                        MxBndleSz = 200
                        PnlsToProduce = 0
                        Do Until componentName <> "Collar22-32" Or dr = dt.Rows.Count - 1
                            PnlsToProduce += dt(dr)(11)
                        Loop
                        Select Case PnlsToProduce
                            Case 50 To 100
                                PnlsToProduce = PnlsToProduce + 1
                            Case 101 To 250
                                PnlsToProduce = PnlsToProduce + 2
                            Case Is > 250
                                PnlsToProduce = PnlsToProduce + 3
                        End Select
                        BuildKnittingRecords(MxBndleSz, componentID, sizeID, PnlsToProduce, qtyppnl, knittOrderID, bundlenum)
                End Select                  
        Next
    End Using
End Sub
```

Hence my question is, why is it doing this and how do I solve it?

This is my code for the `BuildknittingRecord()` sub, not sure if it's relevant in solving my issue:

```
Private Sub BuildKnittingRecords(ByRef MaxBundleSz As Integer, ByRef compID As Integer, ByRef sizeID As Integer, ByRef PnlsToproduce As Integer, ByRef QtyPerPanel As Integer, ByRef KnittingOrderID As Integer, ByRef bundlenum As Integer)
    pnls2prod = PnlsToproduce
    Dim cmdstring As String
    Do Until pnls2prod < 10
        If bundlenum < 10 Then
            bundleNo = txtbatchno.Text & "-K0" & bundlenum
        Else
            bundleNo = txtbatchno.Text & "-K" & bundlenum
        End If
        bundlenum += 1
        If pnls2prod <= MaxBundleSz Then
            PanelsToMake = pnls2prod
            cmdstring = " INSERT INTO [KN - KnittingDetailsHeader] (BatchNo, BundleNo, ComponentID, SizeID, PanelsToMake, QtyPerPanel, KnittingOrderID) VALUES('" & txtbatchno.Text & "', '" & bundleNo & "', " & compID & ", " & sizeID & ", " & PanelsToMake & ", " & QtyPerPanel & ", " & KnittingOrderID & ");"
            Using con As New OleDbConnection(cnString)
                Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(cmdstring)
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                cmd.Connection = con
                cmd.Connection.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
            Exit Do
        Else
            If pnls2prod < 10 Then
                PanelsToMake = pnls2prod + MaxBundleSz
                cmdstring = " INSERT INTO [KN - KnittingDetailsHeader] (BatchNo, BundleNo, ComponentID, SizeID, PanelsToMake, QtyPerPanel, KnittingOrderID) VALUES('" & txtbatchno.Text & "', '" & bundleNo & "', " & compID & ", " & sizeID & ", " & PanelsToMake & ", " & QtyPerPanel & ", " & KnittingOrderID & ");"
                Using con As New OleDbConnection(cnString)
                    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(cmdstring)
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    cmd.Connection.Open()
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End Using
                Exit Do
            End If
            PanelsToMake = MaxBundleSz
            pnls2prod = pnls2prod - MaxBundleSz
            cmdstring = " INSERT INTO [KN - KnittingDetailsHeader] (BatchNo, BundleNo, ComponentID, SizeID, PanelsToMake, QtyPerPanel, KnittingOrderID) VALUES('" & txtbatchno.Text & "', '" & bundleNo & "', " & compID & ", " & sizeID & ", " & PanelsToMake & ", " & QtyPerPanel & ", " & KnittingOrderID & ");"
            Using con As New OleDbConnection(cnString)
                Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(cmdstring)
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                cmd.Connection = con
                cmd.Connection.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: PnlsToProduce += dt(dr)(11) does not change any of the values that would permit the loop to exit.

Comment: Neither `componentName` nor `dr` change in your loop so the condition `componentName <> "Collar22-32" Or dr = dt.Rows.Count - 1` is never met

Comment: Thanks. I sorted out the infinite loop by adding dr += 1 within the do until loop but now it's not giving me the desired outcome